# NameError: name 'StaticLiveServerCase' is not defined

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-testing

I am using django 1.7 . i am practicing Harry Percival's TDD with python book . i am following the book but somewhere that gives unexpected error

```
NameError: name 'StaticLiveServerCase' is not defined
```

I am searched for it but i did not get anything  Can any one tell me about this ? Chapter 8 page no 131 in that book .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the class should be [`StaticLiveServerTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.testing.StaticLiveServerTestCase). [It is renamed just before the 1.7 release.](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23374)

I think the book is based on the beta version of Django 1.7.

**UPDATE**

Make sure import it:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
```

Comment: i tried what you just told me , but same error NameError: name 'StaticLiveServerTestCase' is not defined.Does the site need to be online ? and this is why i am getting error ?

Comment: @sagar, Did you import it? I update the answer to include `import` statement. Check it out.